# Error handling in HAPI

Tags: error-handling, hapi.js

Catch all and any errors in a hapi request lifecycle.
I have a signup handler,

```
public signup(request: Hapi.Request, reply: Hapi.Base_Reply) {
    this.database.user.create(request.payload).then((user: any) => {
        return reply({
            "success": true
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        reply(Boom.conflict('User with the given details already exists'));
    });
}
```

Now, I am catching the error, but I can't be always sure that I will get this error message only. What if there is an error in the database? 
How to catch such database errors or any other unknown errors for all the requests. ???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to return the `err.message` in your reply like

```
reply(Boom.conflig(err.message))
```

or if you want to manage or manipulate the error you have to verify the type of error like

```
if (err instanceof DatabaseError) {
   // manage database error
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a way to handle such errors in Hapi.
What I was looking for was a PreResponse handler. Now, the PreResponse handler can log all the errors and I can throw a 500 error response.

What I am saying is by simply writing

```
reply(err)
```

I can send a 500 error and can catch this error using preResponse handler. Something like this,

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', (request: Hapi.Request, reply: Hapi.ReplyWithContinue) => {
        const response = request.response;
        if (!response.isBoom) { // if not error then continue :)
            return reply.continue();
        }
        console.log(response);
        return reply(response);
    });
```

Comment: If you just want to log the errors, you can use the `hapi-good` module https://github.com/hapijs/good